# Paypal Authentication error while creating connection in .Net Framework 4.5

Tags: .net, paypal, .net-4.0, tls1.2

Paypal Sdk throwing error "The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel" while it was working fine in past. Let me know if there is any solution to that. Note I am using .NET Framework 4.0.

Comment: Look up details about the POODLE vulnerability.  You need to make sure your server software stack can fall back to TLS 1.2 with the HTTP requests.  Right now it must not be.  PayPal just flipped the switch on this on 1/19/16, so that's why it worked before and doesn't now.

Comment: I understand but .NET 4.0 support TLS upto 1.0 and as per my research, i need to upgrade project to 4.5 and thus change TLS to v1.2. I don't want to upgrade as it will consume time at large scale. SO any alternative ??

Comment: No, there is no alternative.  PayPal's server (and many other service providers now) are only going to accept TLS 1.2+

Answer (score 2):

I was also facing the same problem. Later I come to know after lots of analysis that Paypal has upgraded its TLS protocols(as per Link ).

For .NET, 4.5 and higher, we can set the HTTP web request protocol to TLS 1.2 to higher, but .NET 4 or lower doesn't support TLS above TLS1. Hence the fix is directly to assign the port for TLS1.2

```
ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = true;
              ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = (SecurityProtocolType)3072;
              ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit = 9999;

      OAuthTokenCredential tokenCredential = new OAuthTokenCredential(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["PayPalClientID"].ToString(), ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["PayPalClientSecret"].ToString());
      string accessToken = tokenCredential.GetAccessToken();
```